# Спарсить сообщества юзеров ВК с условием (VK API, Python)

Tags: python, парсер, api, вконтакте

Работаю с VK API в Python. У меня есть список пользователей, сообщества которых я собираю ссылками. Но при этом у меня есть список сообществ, которые надо исключить из результата выдачи. Куда нужно вставить это самое условие исключения и как оно должно выглядеть? Спасибо.

```
session = vk.Session()
vk_api = vk.API(session)
dict_groups={}
for i in tqdm(range(len(users))):
    try:
        groups_of_users = vk_api.groups.get(access_token = token, user_id=str(users.loc[i][0]), v = 5.103)
        dict_groups[users.loc[i][0]] = groups_of_users['items']
        time.sleep(0.01)
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените функцию **filter** к результату **dict_groups**.

Я не знаю, что там отдает API VK, поэтому покажу на примере условно -- допустим, у Вас есть следующие данные в **dict_groups**:

```
dict_groups = {'a': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 5), 'b': (1, 2), 'd': (3, 3)}
```

В этом случае после применения функции **filter**:

```
dict_groups_new  = dict(filter(lambda x: (x[1][0], x[1][1]) < (5, 5), dict_groups.items()))
# где x[1][0], x[1][1]) < (5, 5) -- условие фильтрации для каждого элемента
```

Вы получите **dict_groups_new** со следующими значениями:

```
{'a': (3, 4), 'b': (1, 2), 'd': (3, 3)}
```

Надеюсь, доступно объяснил...

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от условия, зачастую его можно отфильтровать ещё на этапе самого запроса, передав параметр filter с нужным значением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> https://vk.com/dev/groups.get

Это удобно тем, что сразу получаешь только ту информацию, которая нужна.